# Pandas array to columns ( need to convert alphabets into words)

Tags: python-3.x

I have data in the below array format, I need to convert this array 
these alphabets into words e.g.
`(' ', 'a', 'd', 'e', 'l', 'o', 'r', 't') = 'adelort'`
how i can do this

```
Array =[(' ', 'a', 'd', 'e', 'l', 'o', 'r', 't'),
 (' ', 'a', 'd', 'e', 'l', 'o', 'r', 't'),
 (' ', 'e', 'i', 'o', 't', 'v'),
 ('d', 'e', 'g', 'i', 'n', 'r', 't'),
 ('d', 'e', 'g', 'i', 'n', 'r', 't'),
 ('a', 'd', 'e', 'i', 'l', 'm', 'n', 't')]
```

Getting above array while working on an NLP problem, please refer  below code:

```
xtest_tfidf = tfidf_vectorizer.transform(pred_test)

y_pred_test = clf.predict(xtest_tfidf)

multilabel_binarizer.inverse_transform(y_pred_test)
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Not sure about the NLP part but you asked how to convert the array into words:

```
Array =[(' ', 'a', 'd', 'e', 'l', 'o', 'r', 't'),
 (' ', 'a', 'd', 'e', 'l', 'o', 'r', 't'),
 (' ', 'e', 'i', 'o', 't', 'v'),
 ('d', 'e', 'g', 'i', 'n', 'r', 't'),
 ('d', 'e', 'g', 'i', 'n', 'r', 't'),
 ('a', 'd', 'e', 'i', 'l', 'm', 'n', 't')]

words = ["".join(x).strip() for x in Array]
```

yields

`['adelort', 'adelort', 'eiotv', 'deginrt', 'deginrt', 'adeilmnt']`